# How to write an function for traversing through a list in typescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I have the following output which needs to be parsed and have to calculate the total in order to display it on the front end in angular 7:-

```
{
    "cart": [
        {
            "id": 28,
            "Name": "Retin a gel",
            "Price": 50,
            "Quantity": 3,
            "Cost": 150,
            "createdAt": "2019-03-15 02:44:55.047 +00:00",
            "updatedAt": "2019-03-15 02:45:04.574 +00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

in want to parse through this output and calculate total which sum of all total cost in typescript as a function to display it on the front end ? can some tell me how design such function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `reduce` with destructuring like so:

```
let totalSum = yourObject.cart.reduce((acc, { Cost }) => acc + Cost, 0);
```

Comment: res.reduce is not a function is displayed

Comment: Edited @Atulkumarsingh

Answer (score 2):

```
object.cart.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.Cost, 0)
```

Just replace object with the name of the object you are parsing and it should work.

Comment: I believe Cost in this context is Price * Quantity from the item object

Comment: Ah yes, indeed =)

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this,I hope it helps

```
let total = 0;
let JsonRes= "{
"cart": [
    {
        "id": 28,
        "Name": "Retin a gel",
        "Price": 50,
        "Quantity": 3,
        "Cost": 150,
        "createdAt": "2019-03-15 02:44:55.047 +00:00",
        "updatedAt": "2019-03-15 02:45:04.574 +00:00"
    }
   ]
 }"

for (let i = 0; i < JsonRes.cart.length(); i++) {
      total  + = +JsonRes.cart[i].Cost; 
}
console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

@yash-rami answer is fine but if you are looking for a function where you can pass your cart details then you can create a function like this:

```
public calculateTotalCost( cart: any[] ) {
    let totalCost = 0;

    for (let cartItemIndex = 0; cartItemIndex < cart.length(); cartItemIndex++) {
         totalCost  + = +cart[ cartItemIndex ].Cost; 
    }

    return totalCost;
}
```

Now where you have your Cart data you can pass it to this function and get the desired result like this.

For example your required data is stored in orderDetails variable then:

```
let orderDetails = {
    "cart": [
        {
            "id": 28,
            "Name": "Retin a gel",
            "Price": 50,
            "Quantity": 3,
            "Cost": 150,
            "createdAt": "2019-03-15 02:44:55.047 +00:00",
            "updatedAt": "2019-03-15 02:45:04.574 +00:00"
        }
    ]
};
```

To store the total cost which you can display in Angular 7 template to show the output on screen suppose you have the variable name totalCostCalculated then:

```
let totalCostCalculated = 0;
```

Now where you want to calculate the end result before displaying to the template use this code:

```
this.totalCostCalculated = this.calculateTotalCost( this.orderDetails.cart );
```

Now you can display the totalCostCalculated value in the template something like this for example:

```
<h1>{{totalCostCalculated}}</h1>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not simple with foreach!

```js
let total = 0;
let JsonRes= `{
"cart": [
    {
        "id": 28,
        "Name": "Retin a gel",
        "Price": 50,
        "Quantity": 3,
        "Cost": 150,
        "createdAt": "2019-03-15 02:44:55.047 +00:00",
        "updatedAt": "2019-03-15 02:45:04.574 +00:00"
    },
    {
        "id": 28,
        "Name": "Retin a gel",
        "Price": 50,
        "Quantity": 3,
        "Cost": 60,
        "createdAt": "2019-03-15 02:44:55.047 +00:00",
        "updatedAt": "2019-03-15 02:45:04.574 +00:00"
    }
   ]
 }`;

var jsonParsed=JSON.parse(JsonRes);
jsonParsed.cart.forEach(x=>total +=x.Cost)
console.log(total);
```